# How to use function(plotname, other input) to print different plots every use

Tags: r, function, plot, ggplot2, save

I am unable to find how to make a function that makes a plot (with ggplot)and then saves that plot with a name that I put into the function as follows:

```
lcaplot <- function(name,lcmodel){
       abc <- ggplot(lcmodel,aes(x = L1, y = value, fill = Var2))
       abc <- abc + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
       abc <- abc + facet_grid(Var1 ~ .) 
       abc <- abc + scale_fill_brewer(type="seq", palette="Greens") +theme_bw()
       abc <- abc + labs(x = "Response Items",y="Probabilities", fill ="Answer categories")
       abc <- abc + theme( axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),                    
                  panel.grid.major.y=element_blank())
```

This part is fine, as it makes the plot I want, but I can't get it to save with the prespecified name:

```
 print(abc)
 ggsave(abc,filename=name,device="png",limitsize=TRUE)
 dev.off() 
 }
```

I've tried multiple things like using a different function (e.g. png() ) or changing the order (first ggsave, then print).

I get the following error message:

```
Saving 6.2 x 3.71 in image.
Error in gsub("%%", "", s) : object 'name' not found.
```

This refers to the input in lcmodel(**name**,lcmodel). I have tried with different things (e.g. function (**xyz***,lcmodel)) here too, but it won't run.

It makes me think that what I'm trying to paste as the name should be either:
 1) a string --> "name" saves a plot that's called name.png, which is fine - except that that means every time I run the code I will save over the old one...

or 
 2)an object. I've tried adding something like:

```
name <- name
```

at the beginning, but it doesn't help any.

Any other way to make multiple plots would be appreciated. I have 60 sets of different data for lcmodel, and I would like to be able to just go:
lcaplot(pic1, lcmodel1)
lcaplot(pic2, lcmodel2)

etc.

Is this even possible? Any input or pointing out dumb mistakes is appreciated!

yours,
Lian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: again Rob Wanders saved the day.

The problem was that I didn't put a string into my function.

So when you use this code, write:

```
 lcaplot("desiredplotname.png",data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch data in a ggplot object by using the `%+%` operator. If you want to make it a function, you can do something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- data.frame(xvar = 1:9, yvar = 1:9)
df2 <- data.frame(xvar = 4:-4, yvar = 4:-4)

plot_1 <- ggplot(df1)+
  aes(x = xvar, y = yvar)+
  geom_point()
plot_1

switch_data <- function(my_plot, new_data){
  output_plot <- my_plot %+% new_data
  return(output_plot)
}

plot_2 <- switch_data(plot_1, df2)
```

Comment: I've been looking at this for some time, but I fail to see how this could solve my problem of printing multiple plots (or more specifically; changing the name within a function). Could you please elaborate?

Comment: oh yeah I think I must have misunderstood what you were aiming to do. Thought you were trying to sub different data. I am not sure what sort of error you are getting, but my first suggestion would be to change the name of your plot object, as `plot` is a pretty widely-used function in R, and could be confusing to the `ggsave` function. What happens when you try your code?

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I've edited my question, to accomodate for your comments. It's not the object name, I've used different ones. Also, I've added the error message.